# Bar Chart lucidworks/Banana

Tags: lucidworks, banana

It is possible to display data in the bar chart as below picture.
*non time_series dashboard*

[screenshot of picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jEWO.jpg)

I try many times, using the bar panel, it can only select 1 field, for example, I select the "Month" field, the bar chart will show the frequency of the month.Below are the sample data.

Month | Sentiment_Score

Jan | 378

Feb | 267

Mar | 247

Apr | 179

May | 945

Jun | 477

Jul | 923

Aug | 348

Sep | 868

Oct | 435

Nov | 328

Dec | 395

Comment: Are you trying to graph 2 or more series (i.e. 2 or more y-values for each x-value)? The screenshot already shows one series which can be done by the panel.

Comment: this is the result showed, when I try to choose month as the field in bar chart.It will show the frequency of month and not the value of month
The screenshot:
https://imgur.com/a/RzGiq

Comment: are you using bar panel or other panels which can be done it?

Comment: If Month is/can be stored as date type, this can be done using a histogram and selecting "values" mode from panel settings. Bar panel displays frequencies of values instead of values which is not what is needed here.